# Could I double team a blocker with Swift Kick?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Swift Kick](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Swift%20Kick)
So lets say I have a 1/1 and another 1/1 on the field

My opponent has a 3/3

I attack with 1/1, and they block with 3/3
If I play [Swift Kick](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Swift%20Kick) on my unused 1/1 making it a 2/1 and target their 3/3 with it (Because [Swift Kick](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Swift%20Kick) says I can, I know you can't declare a new attacker after your first ones)

What happens?

Would their 3/3 kill my 2/1, then lose the 2 damage and kill my 1/1 and live

Or
Would their 3/3 kill my 2/1, and take 2 damage, and kill my 1/1 and take one damage and die?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second one. Damage that you do to a creature lasts until the end of a turn, and then it wears off. So you can do it 2 damage first with Swift Kick, then after that do it 1 damage with normal combat damage.